# Regex matching multiple lines in one match group

Tags: php, regex

I've got the following string:

```
<div>Some headline - list 1<br />
&gt; List item 1<br />
&gt; List item 2<br />
&gt; List item 3<br />
<br />
List 2<br />
&gt; foo<br />
&gt; bar<br />
&gt; baz<br />
<br />
&nbsp;</div>
```

It contains two maleformed lists. It is my goal to wrap the items of these lists into `<ul>`. To accomplish that, I am looking for a regex that matches all Items of each list into one match group.

So my expected result would be:

```
&gt; List item 1<br />
&gt; List item 2<br />
&gt; List item 3<br />
```

and

```
&gt; foo<br />
&gt; bar<br />
&gt; baz<br />
```

All regex magic I tired failed because they did match only a single line of the list, or the match group was including all the content between the beginning of the first list and the end of the last one.

I've tried `~&gt; (.*)<br />\s~gis` which matches both of the lists.

Comment: Please add a tag as to which programming language you are using as different regex implementations have different ways of solving this.

Comment: You were close, just change the quantifier to a lazy one - [**`&gt; (.*?)<br />\s`**](https://regex101.com/r/muQv6G/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex, To capture only the Lists.,

Im using java regex.,

```
(&gt; .*(?:<br\s/>\s+List\s2<br\s/>)?)
```

It captures these elements.,

```
&gt; List item 1<br />
&gt; List item 2<br />
&gt; List item 3<br />
&gt; foo<br />
&gt; bar<br />
&gt; baz<br />
```

Comment: Thank you, but the matches seem not to be in one match group. Its just a match line by line.